# Setting Page Title with React-Router-Config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, page-title

I would like to set the page titles via the config file that I'm using with `react-router-config` but I'm not sure the best approach. Props? Helmet?

routes.js

```
const routes = [
    {
        title: 'Home',
        path: '/',
        exact: true,
        component: PageOne,
        name: PageOne,
    },
    {
        title: 'PageOne',
        path: '/PageOne',
        exact: true,
        component: PageOne,
        name: PageOne,
    }
]
```

template.js

```
const Template = ({ route }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Nav route={route} />
        </>
    )
}
```

nav.js

```
const Nav = () => {
    return (
        <div>
             <Link to="/">Home</Link>
             <Link to="/PageOne">Page One</Link>
        </div>
    )
}
```

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
        <BrowserRouter>{renderRoutes(routes)}</BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using client side routing and react-hooks, you can simply write a custom hook that sets document title

```
const useDocumentTitle = (title) => {
    useEffect(() => {
       document.title = title
    }, [ title])
}
```

and use it within each or your component

```
const PageOne = ({ title }) => {
    useDocumentTitle(title);
    return (
        <>
            {/* Your content here */}
        </>
    )
}
```